# Is Latin Proto-Romance?

Tags: names

Proto languages are usually unwritten but can be reconstructed to a certain point based on what they left behind in “daughter languages”. But, I feel that Latin (classical and vulgar) are part of one proto language: proto romance. Is this a valid theory? Explain.

Answer (score 5):

"Proto-X" tends to be used for the *last* common ancestor of X—the point at which the X languages started to diverge and become their own entities. This is why you'll sometimes hear about "pre-Proto-Indo-European": PIE is the last common ancestor of the Indo-European languages, and "pre-PIE" is what might have come before it. (It mostly comes up in discussions of "this feature of PIE is very weird, it makes more sense if it used to be like *this* in pre-PIE, and then evolved into *that*".)

So, Proto-Romance is the last common ancestor of the Romance languages (*): the particular variety of Vulgar Latin that was spoken at a particular point in the Roman Empire, before all the dialects diverged enough to be considered different languages. Classical Latin and Vulgar Latin itself had diverged from a common ancestor, which I suppose you could call "Proto-Latin", a few centuries before that. And before that was Proto-Latino-Faliscan, and then Proto-Italic, and then Proto-Italo-Venetic, and then (arguably) Proto-Italo-Celtic, and so on.

(*) Except Sardinian/Sard, which may or may not be considered a Romance language—it did come from Latin, but diverged at a very different point than any of the others, which one might call "Proto-Sardinio-Romance" or something like that.